# Fetch data from an ajax call and populate template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am trying to display data fetched from an ajax call using backbone and underscore.

In FF it works but Chrome is reporting an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined`.

(data is referring to template data `<% _.each(data, function(g) { %>` )

Please see my code below.

**collection:**

```
define(['backbone','models/aModel'], function(Backbone, aModel) {
  var aCollection =  Backbone.Collection.extend({       
    url: "api/a",
    model: aModel,
    parse: function(response){              
      return response.data; 
    }       
  });
  return aCollection;
});
```

**model**:

```
define(['underscore', 'backbone'], function(_, Backbone) {
  var aModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'api/b',
  });
  return aModel;
});
```

**view:**

```
define(['jquery','underscore','backbone','models/aModel','collections/aCollection','text!templates/a.html'], function($, _, Backbone, aModel, aCollection,  aTemplate){
      var aView = Backbone.View.extend({
        render: function() {
          var self = this;
          this.collection = new aCollection();
          this.collection.fetch({
            success: function(collection, response) {
              self.$el.html(_.template(aTemplate, {data:self.collection.toJSON()}));
            },
            error: function(collection, response) {
               alert("error");
            }
          });       
          return this;
        },      
      });
      return aView;
    });
```

**template:**

```
<% _.each(data, function(g) { %> 
  <tr>
    <td><%=g.a%></td>
    <td><%=g.b%></td>
    <td><%=g.c%></td>
    <td><%=g.d%></td>
  </tr> 
<% }); %>
```

**data:**

```
{"data": [{"a":"1","b":"name1","c":"0000-00-00","d":x},{"a":"2","b":"name2","c":"0000-00-00","d":y}]}
```

and here is the solution
replace this:

```
self.$el.html(_.template(aTemplate, {data:self.collection.toJSON()}));
```

with this:

```
var compiledTemplate = _.template(aTemplate);
self.$el.html(compiledTemplate({data:self.collection.toJSON()}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a JsFiddle, to help.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rcarvalho/0t8envp1/)

this is working for me on google chrome. If you follow this one, i guess that your problem will be solved.

> $(function() {
>       var compiled = _.template($("#template").html());
>
> ```
> $("#here").html(compiled({
>     data: 
>              [
>                  {"a":"1","b":"name1","c":"0000-00-00","d":"x"},
>                  {"a":"2","b":"name2","c":"0000-00-00","d":"y"}
>              ]
>
> }));
> ```
>
> });

I guess that the variable "aTemplate" is not being compiled using chrome.

Comment: your answer helped me to find solution, I just splitted "compile" and "providing data" to template and it's works ...will update my own post